# How to create a UI based on a Localization Object in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, localization

I have a scenario in a web based application where a user selects a Country from a dropdown list. Once the country is selected, the localized fields beneath the country listbox appears as well correspoding to that country. Here i also need to have that country pre-selected and dropdowns pre-populated based on the locale of that country.

Let me illustrate this with examples:

**EXAMPLES**:

```
Country: United States

Corresponding Fields:
State:
Zip Code:
Time: 
Currency:
Date:



Country: United Kingdom  

Corresponding Fields:
County:
Postal Code:
Time: 
Currency:
Date:



Country: India

Corresponding Fields:
Province:
District:
PO Box: 
Currency:
Date:
Time:
```

How can i achieve this dinamically in ASP.Net (3.5 or 4.0)?

Wonder if we can use a Google Web Service API for this requirement?
Looking forward to seek answers with proven experience. Thanks

Comment: Hi,what do you mean by stating "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources"?
It makes me doubt I should write an answer to your question since I may be not official or credible to you.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that number of fields for country 'India' is 1 more than the others. Is this intended ? If yes, you can setup fields related to a country in database and their localized text be stored in other 'linked' table. Number of fields may differ in number for each country.

If the fields are going to be same, you can create resource files specific to locales and add different text to it. When you change the selection in drop-down, just set `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` to relevant locale code.

Answer (score 1):

Making use of resource files to store the translated texts will provide you more flexibility in the long run.

Do check out the following links on how to make use of resource files:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334820/Using-Globalization-and-Localization-in-ASP-NET

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14818/ASP-NET-2-0-Globalization-Localization-solution

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much about localization but about market-specific standards. Specifically, international address formats. I'm not aware of an off-the-shelf solution for this but you can find existing resources that define these formats (for example on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195167.aspx).

I suppose you could define the formats using your preferred approach (perhaps XML, perhaps hardcoded data definitions) for each market to define its adequate "structure" (by structure I mean which fields and in which order) and use standard localization to translate each of the corresponding labels.

**Edit:**

Regarding Date, Time and Currency, you can make use of the .NET Framework's culture definitions, which can be accessed through CultureInfo's DateTimeFormat and NumberFormat properties ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat.aspx)). I'm not sure whether you want to display Date, Time and Currency through an example (such as today's date or the current time) or the format itself (such as mm/dd/yy and hh:mm:ss). For the former, you instantiate a CultureInfo and pass it in to the ToString overrides that take an IFormatProvider. A good example for Date and Time is shown on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx). The same applies to currency formatting ([MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ztz0sa.aspx)). It works like this:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB"); // Change en-GB to the desired culture name
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string sampleTime = now.ToString("T", cultureInfo); // Result: 5:04:32 PM
string sampleDate = now.ToString("d", cultureInfo); // Result: 13/3/2012
double value = 16325.62901; 
string sampleCurrency = value.ToString("C", cultureInfo); // Result: £16,325.63
```

If on the other hand you want to show the format, you can get this data by taking the relevant properties of DateTimeFormatInfo and NumberFormatInfo. For example:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
string shortDatePattern = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern; // Result: d/M/yyyy 
string shortTimePattern = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern; // Result: h:mm tt 
string currencySymbol = cultureInfo.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol; // Result: £
```

Comment: What about Date, Time and Currency?

Comment: That is indeed a valuable piece of information. Also can you please discuss the scenario of Zip Code/Postal Code/PO Box. For instance, for Canada we have a separate rule(FYI: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postal_codes_in_Canada) and for UK(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_postal_code) we have a separate rule. Thanks